# control net of the torus

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I want to make a complete control net of a torus. However, the net is not closed. Can anyone solve this problem?

```
pts6 = Table[{(2 + 1 Cos [s])*Cos [t], (2 + 1 Cos [s])*Sin[t], 1 Sin[s]},
  {s, -Pi, Pi}, {t, -Pi, Pi}];
f = BSplineFunction[pts6, SplineClosed -> {True, True}];
Show[
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Black, Map[Point, pts6]}],
  Graphics3D[{Gray, Line[pts6], Gray, Line[Transpose[pts6]]}],
  ParametricPlot3D[f[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]]
```

[image: torus with control grid]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEI6o.png)

Comment: pts6 = Table[{(2 + 1 Cos[s])*Cos[t], (2 + 1 Cos[s])*Sin[t], 
    1 Sin[s]}, {s, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}, {t, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}]; You have to set an corresponding step size:pts6 = Table[{(2 + 1 Cos[s])*Cos[t], (2 + 1 Cos[s])*Sin[t], 
    1 Sin[s]}, {s, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}, {t, -Pi, Pi, Pi/4}];

Comment: Thank you for your explain, and now i already get it!

Answer (score 2):

Ulrich's solution fully answers the question, however, there's a problem with the surface created by `BSpliceFunction`. Notice that the surface is not a torus, and there's a break at the interior radius (there's a sharp shadow which should be smooth). Use `pts6` from Ulrich's solution, and `f` from the question.

```
pts6 = Table[{(2 + Cos[t])*Cos[s], (2 + Cos[t])*Sin[s], Sin[t]}, {s, 
    Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 6]}, {t, Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 6]}];
f = BSplineFunction[pts6, SplineClosed -> {True, True}];
g1 = Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Black, Map[Point, pts6]}],
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Gray, Line[pts6], Line[Transpose[pts6]]}],
  ParametricPlot3D[f[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: original solution]

The view from above shows the mesh is unevenly spaced and the surface is not a torus. The cross-section is not circular.

```
ParametricPlot3D[f[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  PlotLabel -> "non-toroidal surface"]
```

[image: view above]

```
ParametricPlot3D[f[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 0 <= y <= 2],
 BoundaryStyle -> Black, Axes -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "non-circular cross-section"]
```

[image: cross-section]

When we use the `BSplineFunction` with the `SplineClosed` option, the control points must not be closed. `BSpineFunction` completes the surface by connecting the boundaries. Fix the problem by redefining the spline function as `f2` to remove the redundant end points. The result is a torus.

```
f2 = BSplineFunction[Most[pts6][[All, ;; -2]], SplineClosed -> {True, True}];
ParametricPlot3D[f2[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}
```

[image: torus]

Here's the corrected view of the control points with the torus, compared to the original graphic.

```
g2 = Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Black, Map[Point, Most@pts6]}],
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Gray, Line[pts6], Line[Transpose[pts6]]}],
  ParametricPlot3D[f2[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: torus with control grid]
[image: original solution]

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the controlpoints is wrong. `{s,-Pi,Pi}` inside `Table` creates an s-grid `{_pi,-Pi+1,-Pi+2,...}` which doesn't contain the last point `Pi`.

Redefine the controlpoints to

```
pts6 = Table[{(2 + 1 Cos[s])*Cos[t], (2 + 1 Cos[s])*Sin[t],1 Sin[s]}, {s, Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 10]}, {t,Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 10]}]
```

Comment: Really appreciate your explaination on it, thank you very much!