# Plot the Corner Control Points

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I face some problem of plotting the control points at the corner. I only want to plot the control points at the corner only. I do not know how to plot the corner control points from all the control points.Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you. here is the code:

```
pts6 = Table[{(2 + 1 Cos[s])*Cos[t], (2 + 1 Cos[s])*Sin[t], 1 Sin[s]},
   {s, Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 10]}, {t, Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 10]}];

f = BSplineFunction[pts6, SplineClosed -> {True, True}];

Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Black, Map[Point, pts6]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Gray, Line[pts6], Gray, Line[Transpose[pts6]]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `f = BSplineFunction[Most[pts6][[All, ;; -2]], SplineClosed -> {True, True}];` to draw a torus. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/234005/41569 for why we need this change.

Comment: Which of the points are corner control points? I think all the points are on a corner of the grid network.